# convert string to integer using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.I have one value ('i.e-001') which datatype is varchar and i convert this into integer and then want to add 1 at each time DB entry.I did something like below.

```
var newcode=parseInt(response.data.code)+1;
```

Here `response.data.code` contains the code `001` and its coming from DB.first user is fetching the latest code(`i.e-001`) from db and increment by 1 then storing in the DB.In this case i am getting newcode value is `2` but I should get `002`,'003',..so on.Please help me.

Comment: _"but I should get 002"_ `002` is not a valid `js` integer

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? It will create many, many problems.

Comment: 2 = 002. What you want is a formatted string.

Comment: Why you want 2 as 002 what was the purpose ?

Comment: what if db has '03' and adding 1 to it should be 004 or 04 ?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using just a good old basic int with auto increment turned on for an ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a small function:

```
<script>
function pad(n, width, z) {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

var len = response.data.code.length;
var newcode=parseInt(response.data.code)+1;
alert(pad(newcode, len));
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4f57wn68/)

Comment: @ MyWay : when `response.data.code` is `011` it is giving the output `010` and also 4 digit case its giving the different output.

Answer (score 1):

After incrementing do the padding again

```
var originalLength = response.data.code.length; //to ensure that new number is of same length
var newcode=parseInt(response.data.code)+1;
while( newcode.toString().length < originalLength  ) //assuming that you want length 3
{
    newcode= "0" + newcode;
}
alert( newcode );
```

Comment: Why not just do `newcode.toString()` in the while loop instead of `newcode+""`? They both work the same but `toString` would make it much more readable.

Comment: @Sam yes it will, making that change. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do parseInt Javascript removes 00 before the number and you get exact 1.

So if you add 1 you get 2.

If you want to get 002 you should try

```
var newcode= '00'+parseInt(response.data.code)+1;
```

For 10 digits just loop it:

```
for(var i=0; i<10-newcode.length; i++){
    newcode = '0'+newcode;
}
```

But the best solution was provided by YeldarKurgmangaliev.

It's terrible mistake to generate ID in jQuery, do it in database.

Comment: If it was `017`, it will become `0018` which seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev :Good catch.so what is the perfect solution.

Comment: @satya The perfect solution is to stop doing this manually and let your DB use integer auto-increment.

Comment: @satya how much digits you want to have?

Comment: @SanatSerikuly:For now its 10

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev : I know that ,But is there any good solution for this  scenario.

Comment: @satya look at other answers

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\d+$)/` to match digit characters

```js
var str = "i.e-009";
str = str.replace(/(\d+$)/, function(match) {
  var n = Number(match) + 1, len = String(n).length
  // if `n` equals `9` , return `"i.e-009"`
  // if `n` equals `10`, return `"i.e-010"`
  // if `n` equals `100` rerurn `"i.e-100"`
  , res = len === 1 ? "00" : len === 2 && "0" || len === 3 && "";
  return res + n
});

console.log(str)
```